# Input value not updating in another activity which I pass in Intents

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-intent, android-button

Mine Main Activity :-

```
  var sec  =  second_activity()
  var button1: Button? = null
  var button2: Button? = null
  var button3: Button? = null
  var button4: Button? = null



button1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.button1) as Button
button2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.button2) as Button
button3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.button3) as Button
button4 = findViewById<View>(R.id.button4) as Button




button1?.setOnClickListener {
    sec.input = "a"
    val intent: Intent = Intent(this, second_activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

}
button2?.setOnClickListener {
    sec.input = "b"
    val intent: Intent = Intent(this, second_activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Second activity :-

```
class second_activity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    var input : String = " "


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

 
        //getting recyclerview from xml
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        //adding a layoutmanager
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        //crating an arraylist to store users using the data class user
        val users = ArrayList<User>()
        //adding some dummy data to the list
        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(this , users)
        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        Toast.makeText(this, input , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        when(input) {

            "a" ->  {
                users.add(User(R.drawable.bc))
            }
            "b" -> {
                users.add(User(R.drawable.bc))
                users.add(User(R.drawable.bc))
                users.add(User(R.drawable.bc))
                users.add(User(R.drawable.bc))
            }

        }



    }
```

Input value is not updating which I pass from MainActivity. It is always taking the blank value which are present in second activity. I also tried by changing the position of Input. but not worked. please help

Is there any other way to find which button is clicked in MainActivity from Second Activity

Comment: *Never* create an instance of an activity yourself. Delete `var sec  =  second_activity()`. You can pass values between activities using `Intent` extras. Or, perhaps this should be a single activity, with two fragments or composables for the separate screens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another way. Use `intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode)`. Then in the second activity you can get that requestCode with `getIntent().getExtra().getInt("requestCode")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the values from one activity to another activity using the following code,

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(name, value)
startActivity(intent)
```

I have given sample code below, please try this..

In first activity, I send the "language" value.

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("language", "tamil")
startActivity(intent)
```

In second activity, I retrived the "language" value.

Put this code in your second activity onCreate()

```
val intent: Intent = getIntent()
var language = ""
if (intent != null) {
   language = intent.getStringExtra("language")
 }
 println("Language : $language")
```